# Resource Consumption of MALLOC in a C Application

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I am writing a C app and I use malloc to create data on the heap.  Now while the application is active, this data is always persistant, so I never "free" the Malloc data.

My question is: will this memory be automatically freed when the application terminates, or must I execute free() manually at the completion of my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is implementation-defined. Strictly following the C standard, you should `free` everything you've `malloc`'d before the application terminates.

Any modern general-purpose operating system, however, will clean up after you, so this is only relevant in some embedded, old-fashioned, or otherwise exotic environments.

As a point of style, do try to `free` every allocated block. It gets you in the habit of writing clean code and preventing memory leaks.

Comment: I can't find any statement or implication in the standard that you "should free" everything you malloc. Naturally the hosted environment and nature of processes is outside the scope of the C language specification, but I can't imagine any OS with a sense of "running a program" where the program's memory is not abandoned to the OS on exit, not even DOS. Surely embedded environments without an OS may not even have a notion of "running the program" or "exiting" in which case the matter is irrelevant.

Comment: @R..: I don't have a copy of the standard ready, but I recall it doesn't specify what happens to malloc'd memory at exit. I've heard (no reference, so this might be just a rumor) that some older mainframe operating systems require explicit `free`, since they have a single address space per user.

Answer (score 2):

It will be freed. This is the wonders of the "process" abstraction. All the resources and memory owned by this running process is freed upon termination.

Note that it took some time to come up with this abstraction, but it is a really nice sandbox for a system. In fact, killing processes is even used as a last resort to try to fix buggy programs that have leaks or degraded performance as they execute for days (it is called with the pretty name of ["Process Rejuvenation"](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/MS.2001.936217), and even exists in conferences and journals, but is really an admittance of a bad design or coding).

Comment: It still kind of depends on the operating system, but yeah, most OS will free the memory.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: at least those with the "process" abstraction :)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be:Could you mention an OS that will not clean up after process termination?

Answer (score -2):

You should never explicitly `free` such memory. At best it will give you no benefit, and at worst it will swap a lot of swapped-out data back into memory just to inspect some bookkeeping pointers and then discard it, thrashing the user's hard drive for no purpose.

Comment: -1 for recommending against one of the best-known practices in most non-OOP languages: "Always free what you allocate". One of the benefits is that it helps you keep the code self-contained, so once you use some code (library routine?) in a different app, and in that app the allocated blocks do not persist until app termination, you'll be able to re-use the code without hassle. Otherwise, you might have a hard time finding which stuff must be free'd when.

Comment: You can give all the -1's you want, but my advice will give a program that behaves better.

Comment: I tend to agree with R, although saying *"never"* seems overly prescriptive.  If your code is library code, it should provide cleanup functions that free used resources - whether to call them or not is then up to the application.  It is certainly true that iterating through large data structures at process exit merely to `free()` them (which often doesn't even return the memory to the OS anyway!) can be a time-consuming piece of busy-work.

Comment: @caf: Indeed, my advice was to the OP's situation where the data persists for the life of the *application*. I agree completely with your comment in the case of library code. And for a great example of slow-exit-due-to-useless-frees, just look at Firefox.

Comment: By the way, another practical consideration nobody considers: if `free` or `realloc` is never called and this property of the application is detectable, the standard library (with some help of the linker) can arrange for `malloc` to essentially redirect to `sbrk`, reducing memory usage by a theoretical maximum of 93% (if all `malloc` calls have an argument of 1) and a real-world-use reduction of 5-25% (on the higher end if lots of small (e.g. 8- to 16-byte) node structures are allocated). The only implementation I know of which does this is one I wrote, though. :-)

Comment: I suspect the Firefox issue is the (closely related) one of cascading C++ object destructors rather than simple `free()` s.

Comment: If you have an application with many tiny allocations like that, you can create your own allocator that has the same behaviour - it would obtain a big chunk with `mmap()`, keep track of the high water mark, and only allow you to deallocate it with a single `munmap()` of the whole lot.  Such an allocator might be useful in library code.

Comment: @caf: I believe GNU obstack is pretty much what you just described, except that it uses `malloc` rather than `mmap`. And that's certainly a good approach for an application that considers its memory usage/malloc performance an issue. The only downside is that there's an upper bound on the amount you can allocate. On the other hand, having the library transparently perform this optimization avoids that limitation, and also avoids putting non-portable hacks (like direct usage of `sbrk`, or even usage of `mmap` in code that wants to target pure C) in application code, so I still like it.

Comment: No -1, but no +1 either. This reeks of premature optimization.

Comment: Simply load too many large apps to fit in ram on your favorite GUI environment, then try to close one. Enjoy waiting 10-15 seconds for it to finish closing (sometimes after the window disappears, then complaining that you can't start a new one because an instance is already running). Then try calling my advice premature optimization. This is a solution to a really annoying real-world problem, not guesswork.